# Sort items leaflet list markers

Tags: leaflet

I'm reading shapefiles with the leaflet library. I should sort the list of map markers that are shown to me on the screen via  and

from the library. I tried to work on the leaflet-list-markers-js file but didn't find the way how to either sort the values into the array or how to sort the array once composed. I don't know if it is possible to act on the html element to sort the element through css.

Help me

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of tools to do this, it would be nice if you share the code or pictures, then it will be easier to try to help you.
To be able to sort objects, you need a criterion or a distinguishing feature by which you will do this. For example, through cycles if or for ... in

Comment: i've update the answer with used code

Comment: Hello, I renew my request, if you can help me you would solve a big problem

Answer (score 0):

So,
this piece of code I use to create the list, markersLayer is a LayerGroup:

```
var list = new L.Control.ListMarkers({layer: markersLayer, itemIcon: null, maxItems: 30, maxZoom: 25});

    list.on('item-mouseover', function (e) {
        e.layer.setIcon(redSelectMarker)
    }).on('item-mouseout', function (e) {
        e.layer.setIcon(transparentIcon)
    });


    myMap.addControl(list);
```

The following lines in the test to the methods that the library uses to update the page content list leaflet-list-markers.min.js, I have been working on this page. _updateList: adds the 'li' html elements that are created with the _createItem method to the a._list list:

```
       _updateList: function () {
            var a = this, b = 0;
            this._list.innerHTML = "ELENCO PUNTI: ", this._layer.eachLayer(function (c) {
                c instanceof L.Marker && a._map.getBounds().contains(c.getLatLng()) && ++b < a.options.maxItems && a._list.appendChild(a._createItem(c))
            });
        },
```

```
_createItem: function (a) {
            var b = L.DomUtil.create("li", "list-markers-li"), c = L.DomUtil.create("a", "", b),
                d = this.options.itemIcon ? '<img src="' + this.options.itemIcon + '" />' : "", e = this;
            return c.href = "#", L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(c).on(c, "click", L.DomEvent.stop, this).on(c, "click", function (b) {
                this._moveTo(a.getLatLng())
            }, this).on(c, "mouseover", function (b) {
                e.fire("item-mouseover", {layer: a})
            }, this).on(c, "mouseout", function (b) {
                e.fire("item-mouseout", {layer: a})
            }, this), a.options.hasOwnProperty(this.options.label) ? c.innerHTML = d + '<span style="opacity: 1">' + a.options[this.options.label] + "</span> <b>" + this.options.itemArrow + "</b>" : console.log("propertyName '" + this.options.label + "' not found in marker"), b
        },
```